# Hard time understanding the basics of Scala

Tags: scala, debugging

I'm a seasoned Python developer and I have to learn Scala for my new job.
I had a great time practicing Python with CodeWars and decided to try with Scala as well, but there's just something that I can't understand...

Bellow I have a partial solution to an exercise, you can find it here https://www.codewars.com/kata/5c8bfa44b9d1192e1ebd3d15/train/scala

```
object SheepAdvisor {
  
  def warnTheSheepCheck(queue: Array[String]): String =
    // println(queue)
    if (queue.last == "wolf") {
      "Pls go away and stop eating my sheep"
    } else {
      s"Oi! Sheep! You are about to be eaten by a wolf!"
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is, why can't I just print the input? If I uncomment the print statement the entire code breaks. It just doesn't make sense to me.

The error:

```
src/main/scala/solution.scala:4: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: String
    println(queue)
           ^
src/main/scala/solution.scala:5: error: not found: value queue
    if (queue.last == "wolf") {
```

I'm really used to just attack a problem by small parts, usually printing stuff to verify that I'm on the right track. Is it some sort of paradigm shift with Scala that I just don't know about?

Any Scala resources focused on people coming from Python would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Scala 2 (available on Codewars) you need to wrap the whole function body in curly brackets otherwise compiler treats `warnTheSheepCheck` as invocation of [`println`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Console$.html#println(x:Any):Unit) which returns [`Unit`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/Unit.html):

```scala
object SheepAdvisor {
  def warnTheSheepCheck(queue: Array[String]): String = {  // here
    println(queue)
    if (queue.last == "wolf") {
      "Pls go away and stop eating my sheep"
    } else {
      s"Oi! Sheep! You are about to be eaten by a wolf!"
    }
  }  // and here
}
```

Scala 3 has [optional braces](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/indentation.html) feature which allows to omit braces in [this case](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tWyyUCXDSZOCmOU22bqJ1A).

Comment: Note that in Scala 3.x, a more python-style indentation-defines-structure syntax is available.  Hopefully the 2-to-3 transition is overall smoother in Scala than it was in Python...

Comment: Scala before 3 is much more in the C tradition, but when braces are left off a method definition, the compiler infers them as wrapping one statement.  So in the debug-by-println approach, you'll tend to put in the `{` and `}` by default everywhere.